# Is there a way to specifically use the second value from a multidimensional array to do calculations

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

for example if I only want to select the number values from the array and calculate the tip amount and also calculate the total sum of the bill.

```
let bill = [["Fish", 23], ["Steak", 10],["Avocado Toast", 15]];

bill.forEach((dish) => {
  dish.forEach((dishAmount)=> {
    console.log(dishAmount);
  })
})
```

Comment: In your example, replace `dishAmount` with `dish[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `reduce` and inside take the second element to add.

```js
const bill = [["Fish", 23], ["Steak", 10],["Avocado Toast", 15]];
console.log('Total Amount: '+bill.reduce((a,[_,amount])=>a+amount,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use object destructuring to access 2nd element (at index 1)

```js
let bill = [["Fish", 23], ["Steak", 10],["Avocado Toast", 15]];

let total = 0;
bill.forEach(({1: dishAmount}) => {
  console.log(dishAmount);
  total += dishAmount;
})

console.log('total', total)

// Alternatively
const total2 = bill.reduce((acc, {1: dishAmount}) => acc + dishAmount, 0)

console.log('total 2', total2)
```